# Looping through csv file in powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a csv file that has been exported from a sql database. The file has 2 columns with 100 records:
**FunctionName** and **DateCreated**

So I want to see each and every object that is referenced by every function in the database.

Here is my code I have written so far:

```
$Query=  "SELECT  space(iteration * 4) + TheFullEntityName + ' (' + rtrim(TheType) + ')', *
               FROM    dbo.fn_DependantObjects('$FunctionName',    1,     0)    
               ORDER BY ThePath"
```

please note:  `dbo.fn_DependantObjects`, is a function I have already created.

```
$fileName = 'c:\CurrentDate.csv'
foreach ($pattern in (Import-Csv $filename | % {$_.FunctionName})) {
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "ServerName" -Database "DatabaseName" -Query $Query
```

I am still new to powershell and would really appreciate if anyone can help me in any other way. I am stuck and this project is behind schedule.

Let me know.

Thanks
Immortal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this line from your query:

```
FROM    dbo.fn_DependantObjects('$FunctionName',    1,     0)
```

It's trying to use string interpolation set the `$FunctionName` variable in the string. However, at the point where you run that code, `$FunctionName` doesn't have a value yet. It's trying to complete the string interpolation when you first assign it to the `$Query` variable, rather than saving the placeholder for each iteration through your loop.

To fix this, you want to move that string variable assignment code down into the loop:

```
$fileName = 'c:\CurrentDate.csv'
foreach ($pattern in (Import-Csv $filename | % {$_.FunctionName})) {
    $Query=  "SELECT  space(iteration * 4) + TheFullEntityName + ' (' + rtrim(TheType) + ')', *
               FROM    dbo.fn_DependantObjects('$FunctionName',    1,     0)    
               ORDER BY ThePath" 
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "ServerName" -Database "DatabaseName" -Query $Query
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the `$Query` string, you use `$FunctionName` to refer to the function name, but in the `foreach()` loop you use `$pattern` - fix this first.

Then, make sure you assign the `$Query` string *after* `$FunctionName` has been assigned:

```
$fileName = 'c:\CurrentDate.csv'
foreach ($FunctionName in Import-Csv $filename | % {$_.FunctionName}) {
    $Query=  "SELECT  space(iteration * 4) + TheFullEntityName + ' (' + rtrim(TheType) + ')', *
               FROM    dbo.fn_DependantObjects('$FunctionName',    1,     0)    
               ORDER BY ThePath" 
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "ServerName" -Database "DatabaseName" -Query $Query
}
```

Answer (score 0):

with -format (-f) like it :

```
Import-Csv $filename | %{
    $Query=  "SELECT  space(iteration * 4) + TheFullEntityName + ' (' + rtrim(TheType) + ')', *
               FROM    dbo.fn_DependantObjects('{0}',    1,     0)    
               ORDER BY ThePath" -f $_.FunctionName
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance "ServerName" -Database "DatabaseName" -Query $Query

}
```